# Subspace of RKHS generated by kernel mean embeddings

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, kernels

Suppose $\mathcal{H_k}$ is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) with reproducing kernel $k: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I am looking for results characterising the smallest subspace of $\mathcal{H}_k$ that contains all elements of the RKHS of the form $\int_X k(\cdot, x) \text{d}P(x)$, for any probability measure $P: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$. After searching through recent papers and classical references, I've got nothing. Any pointers appreciated!

Happy to impose sensible conditions on the kernel or the measures -- for instance, kernel is characteristic/continuous/isotropic, measure has a pdf.

Comment: The closure of such a subspace is $\mathcal H_k$ itself, i.e., it is a pre-Hilbert space.

Comment: thanks -- do you have a reference, or hints on how to prove that?

Comment: Take P(x) the uniform measure on $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Then you get roughly the usual construction of an RKHS...